# Magento2 enabling elasticsearch empties all categories

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch and the Magento backend connection test to elasticsearch is successful. 
If I save settings, clear the cache and reindex as described in the Magento devdocs, all product cateogries are empty and my search function has no result, whatever I type in there. I can still access the products with the direct url, thats all. 
If I switch back to MYSQL as search engine and clear the cache all products are back. 
Both Magento and Elasticsearch are Ubuntu18.04 servers, Magento 2.3.2 and Elasticsearch 6.8.3.
Any idea where I can take a deeper look or how this problem can be solved?

**EDIT:** Some product attributes were not enabled for search (but not all! So there must have been results before). I reindexed and now the ES shows very good results! But as before, product pages are empty.

**EDIT 2**: Its a Multistore. The website id 1 works with ES, all other websites have no search results – and everywhere empty categories.

Comment: Change one of the category layout from admin. Empty layout or no design updates may create issue

Comment: All categories were set to use the parent category setting, and the parent category is set to 1 column layout. Changes in any way do not lead to a changed behavior of the category content – they are still empty but I can see different column layouts depending on my choice ;-)

Comment: Refer elastic search logs, and Put some logs on below class. This will ensure that ES is returning some products
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/SearchAdapter/DocumentFactory.php

Comment: I saw some product attributes were not enabled for search. Now I reindexed and the search shows very good results! But still, product pages are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer after some time: It was due to the simple fact that Elasticsearch was started, running for a short time and then crashed in silence.

Elasticsearch costs a lot of RAM (about half of your machine if not configured for less RAM usage) and indexation can cost a lot of RAM which then let Elasticsearch crash and all product categories were empty.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues are still with sorting when an elastic search is using as a catalog search engine.
To resolve it, you can apply below patch specifically to **Magento 2.3.2** and **Elasticsearch 6+**.

Go to the below file and add a [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) on the below class.

```
Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplier.php
```

Find `apply()` method and replace it with the below function. 
This is hotfix introduced by Magento recently by adding `$this->collection->setPageSize(null);` to the `SearchResultApplier.php` class.

```
    public function apply()
    {
        if (empty($this->searchResult->getItems())) {
            $this->collection->getSelect()->where('NULL');
            return;
        }
        $ids = [];
        foreach ($this->searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $ids[] = (int)$item->getId();
        }
        $this->collection->setPageSize(null);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id IN (?)', $ids);
        $orderList = join(',', $ids);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER);
        $this->collection->getSelect()->order("FIELD(e.entity_id,$orderList)");
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Do you know about how to add custom filter when apply elasticsearch? It's proper working in mysql. When I set elasticsearch, My custom filter not display in layered navigation.

Comment: @RohanHapani Sorry do not have a proper answer on that. You can do a couple of things like 1. check elasticsearch mappings and make any changes into it 2. try to change ElasticVersion upgrade maybe help. I saw ur que while back. For Custom Filter, it needs more work if it not reflected in the current ElasticSearch mappings.

Comment: If you have any answer. then please post here. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/301847/51810

Comment: Hi @RohanHapani do you find solution for applying custom filter in category page with elasticsearch ?

Comment: HI @RohanHapani also I need to display out of stock product at end of collection in category page, it is working fine in Mysql Search but not in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
The issue is happened because of 2 attribute “jajuma_product_latitude” and “jajuma_product_longitude“ don’t show in store view.
I’ve change 2 parameters of this 2 attributes and run this command:

```
php bin/magento c:f && php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

And the products are show as expected in categories.

[image]
[image]

 Hope it help.