# Magento 2.2.6 Product Pages Not Opening after upgrade

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, redirect, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

The product detail pages on my site are no longer opening after upgrading from magento 2.2 to 2.2.6

There are no error rather 
a catalog search results page is loading instead

http://mydomain.co.uk/catalogsearch/result

I have tried restoring .htaccess files (as many as i could find) however I know I dont have all of them in any case it may be something else but it was working without any issue before upgrade - I have tried running a url rewrite too for full site but this did not fix issue

I have tried with and without elasticsearch on the site but makes no different product pages are not opening

Please can someone help

Comment: Have a look at the answer. it may help you. 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/293001/34579