# Magento 2 ElasticSearch Empty Categories

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am running Magento 2.3.5-p1 with ElasticSearch 7.
When ElasticSearch is set as the search engine, all my categories are shown empty. This happens with every version of ElasticSearch. When the search engine is set back to MySQL, the products show in categories as normal.

I tried the fix [outlined here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/291190/magento2-enabling-elasticsearch-empties-all-categories) but my categories still display empty whenever ElasticSearch is enabled.

Comment: Are you using any third party layered navigation modules?